# How do you set the username (APP_USER) as the email from single-sign on in APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm setting up an APEX app using single-sign on following [this tutorial](https://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2018/02/apex-authentication-with-microsoft-account.html) and the app now allows sign-in to occur. However the value of APP_USER does not equal the email address that is logged in through Microsoft - it defaults to APEX_PUBLIC_USER. I want to use the username to provide role-based application access control.

I've looked around for solutions and found [post authentication code](http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/facebook-google-and-custom.html) that looks like it should help and I have tried to adapt.

Using

```
procedure post_authenticate
is
begin
    w14_auth_pkh.post_authenticate(
        p_username => :APP_USER);
end post_authenticate
```

or

`apex_custom_auth.set_user (p_user => :APP_USER);`

I get the following error messages when applying changes from within the authenticate scheme section:

ORA-06550: line 8, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

or

ORA-06550: line 2, column 17: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following: constant exception   table columns long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar The symbol "" was substituted for "." to continue.

Answer (score 2):

You first code sample uses a package of Dimitri's, and is missing a semi-colon at the end.

Your relevant code would be
APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.SET_USER();

[image]

Alternatively, you could change the Username attribute to something that has been made available via the user info endpoint URL.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used your first suggestion and it removed the errors. Although I think that I was using `select user from dual;` incorrectly (I was running from the SQL workshop) so the result is still APEX_PUBLIC_USER. However if I run `SELECT *
FROM   apex_workspace_log_summary_usr
WHERE  workspace = ‘MY_WORKSPACE’
AND apex_user != ‘nobody’
AND last_view > sysdate – 15 / 24 / 60;` it returns APEX_USER as an MS email. Is 'select user from dual;' the correct way to reference a current user from within the app?

Comment: No, USER is not the correct reference. Your original use of :APP_USER is correct. However, why this is returning "APEX_PUBLIC_USER" is pretty darn strange. Do you have a Username Attribute?